# Image conversion and view in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, jpeg, tiff, image-conversion

I have a bytearray of a tiff image. When I convert into the same format, image opens. But when I convert it into jpg, it doesn't (in Chrome, but works in IE).
PS: I want to directly convert the bytearray to show image dynamically as per my requirement.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
bOutStream = < ... Tiff image Stream Received from my API Call... > 
byte[] chqImage = bOutStream.toByteArray(); 
response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); 
BufferedOutputStream output = null; 
output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream()); 
output.write( bOutStream.toByteArray()); 
output.flush();
```

Comment: Can you describe *how* you converted the image from tiff to jpeg?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream bOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bOutStream = < ... Tiff image Stream Received from my API Call... >
byte[] chqImage = bOutStream.toByteArray() ;
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
BufferedOutputStream output = null;
output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
output.write( bOutStream.toByteArray());
output.flush();

Comment: So, you've set the content type to `image/jpeg` but you haven't actually transformed the image into jpeg format -- you are still sending the unmodified tiff.

Comment: okay thanks,let you know

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to actually translate the image itself from TIFF to JPEG.  To do that, I recommend reviewing the [ImageIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#createImageInputStream(java.lang.Object)) library in Java.

I feel like the javadoc for that library is pretty straightforward, so you should be OK there.